# What's the difference between disabled="disabled" and readonly="readonly" for HTML form input fields?

Tags: html, cross-browser

I have read a bit on this, but I can't seem to find anything solid about how different browsers treat things.

Comment: related: "how to emulate the readonly attribute for a select tag, and still get the POST data?" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368813/html-form-readonly-select-tag-input

Answer (score 895, accepted):

A `readonly` element is just not editable, but gets sent when the according `form` submits. A `disabled` element isn't editable and isn't sent on submit. Another difference is that `readonly` elements can be focused (and getting focused when "tabbing" through a form) while `disabled` elements can't.

Read more about this in [this great article](https://web.archive.org/web/20150913195206/https://kreotekdev.wordpress.com/2007/11/08/disabled-vs-readonly-form-fields/) or [the definition by w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.12). To quote the important part:

> **Key Differences**
>
> **The Disabled attribute**
>
> - Values for disabled form elements are not passed to the processor method. The W3C calls this a successful element.(This works similar to
>     form check boxes that are not checked.)
> - Some browsers may override or provide default styling for disabled form elements. (Gray out or emboss text) Internet Explorer
>     5.5 is particularly nasty about this.
> - Disabled form elements do not receive focus.
> - Disabled form elements are skipped in tabbing navigation.
>
> **The Read Only Attribute**
>
> - Not all form elements have a readonly attribute. Most notable, the `<SELECT>` , `<OPTION>` , and `<BUTTON>` elements do not have readonly
>     attributes (although they both have disabled attributes)
> - Browsers provide no default overridden visual feedback that the form element is read only. (This can be a problem… see below.)
> - Form elements with the readonly attribute set will get passed to the form processor.
> - Read only form elements can receive the focus
> - Read only form elements are included in tabbed navigation.

Comment: on readonly element you can't use CTRL + C but you can use right mouse click and select Copy.

Comment: @Rumplin are you sure about that? I just tested and was able to copy with the keyboard shortcut in Chrome on OS X.

Comment: "Not all form elements have a readonly attribute. Most notable, the <SELECT> , <OPTION> , and <BUTTON> elements do not have readonly attributes (although thy both have disabled attributes)". Thats why sometimes you have to use "disabled" attribute with a hidden input field for select forms.

Comment: In the current version of Chrome readonly elements cannot receive focus. This is problematic if you are expecting users to be able to scroll through values that are longer than the size of the input.

Comment: Also, if you're using Angularjs ng-readonly="true" allows the input to receive focus on Chrome, ie and firefox at least. It still does not allow scrolling to see the entire contents of a truncated input, but you can at least copy the text.

Comment: So it is my understanding that `disabled` *implies* `readonly` but `readonly` does not imply `disabled`. In other words if an element has the `disabled` attribute then there is no need to also include the `readonly` attribute. Correct?

Comment: Well i came here to correct the comment above me but then i realized it was my past self :facepalm:. But to answer my own question: no, `disabled` does not imply `readonly`. Values of `disabled` inputs do not get sent with the form data on submit, whereas values of `readonly` inputs do.

Answer (score 99):

No events get triggered when the element is having disabled attribute.

None of the below will get triggered.

```
$("[disabled]").click( function(){ console.log("clicked") });//No Impact
$("[disabled]").hover( function(){ console.log("hovered") });//No Impact
$("[disabled]").dblclick( function(){ console.log("double clicked") });//No Impact
```

While readonly will be triggered.

```
$("[readonly]").click( function(){ console.log("clicked") });//log - clicked
$("[readonly]").hover( function(){ console.log("hovered") });//log - hovered
$("[readonly]").dblclick( function(){ console.log("double clicked") });//log - double clicked
```

Answer (score 44):

Disabled means that no data from that form element will be submitted when the form is submitted. Read-only means any data from within the element will be submitted, but it cannot be changed by the user.

For example:

```
<input type="text" name="yourname" value="Bob" readonly="readonly" />
```

This will submit the value "Bob" for the element "yourname".

```
<input type="text" name="yourname" value="Bob" disabled="disabled" />
```

This will submit nothing for the element "yourname".

Comment: Both `readonly` and `disabled` are boolean values. Use `disabled` instead of `disabled="disabled"` (same for readonly)

Comment: Both are semantically correct. HTML5 allows you to use either.

Comment: Context-free admonition to use only the attribute names, without values, is ill-advised - because then the code will not be valid XML/XHTML. I know a lot of devs don't care about those, but they should at least be aware of the pitfall. Personally I strive for XHTML compliance - unless given a compelling reason, which I haven't received yet - so I use the long/duplicated form.

Comment: @underscore_d - I find the long duplicated form cumbersome. Why not use an empty string, which is also permitted?  `readonly=""`

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Do you have a spec citation that empty strings are valid XHTML? I can only find commentary pages saying it's valid for HTML5. Everyone I've seen talking about XHTML say that its form for boolean attributes must be `attrname="attrname"`. Either way, it doesn't seem to be particularly well-documented, at least not that I can find. Well, there's this - https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.3.4.2 - but it only specifically mentions SGML and HTML, not XHTML.... too many acronyms :S

Comment: ...but skipping over the bit for HTML, where presence/absence is sufficient - we get this, which presumably applies by omission to XHTML: `Boolean attributes may legally take a single value: the name of the attribute itself (e.g., selected="selected").` So the empty string doesn't seem to be valid.

Comment: @underscore_d [According to the WHATWG spec (HTML5 as of 2020)](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attributes): If a boolean attribute has a value (which would make it XML-compliant), there are only two valid values: the empty string, or a case-insensitive match for the attribute name. So `selected=""` is legal in HTML5.

Comment: @chharvey I was talking about XHTML, not HTML.

Answer (score 5):

Same as the other answers (disabled isn't sent to the server, readonly is) but some browsers prevent highlighting of a disabled form, while read-only can still be highlighted (and copied).

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp

> A read-only field cannot be modified. However, a user can tab to it, highlight it, and copy the text from it.

Answer (score 3):

If the value of a disabled textbox needs to be retained when a form is cleared (reset), `disabled = "disabled"` has to be used, as read-only textbox will not retain the value

For Example:

HTML

Textbox

```
<input type="text" id="disabledText" name="randombox" value="demo" disabled="disabled" />
```

Reset button

```
<button type="reset" id="clearButton">Clear</button>
```

In the above example, when Clear button is pressed, disabled text value will be retained in the form. Value will not be retained in the case of `input type = "text" readonly="readonly"`

Answer (score 1):

The difference between disabled and readonly is that read-only controls can still function and are still focusable, anddisabled controls can not receive focus and are not submitted with the form

Answer (score 0):

The readonly attribute can be set to keep a user from changing the value until some other conditions have been met while the disabled attribute can be set to keep a user from using the  element

Answer (score 0):

Basically, a read-only attribute means the element can't be edited by the user, but is sent with the form.
A disabled attribute however means that the element can't be edited by the user, and won't be sent with the form. (P.S. Disabled elements also have lower opacity)