# Jquery - Show a javascript alert box when you click on a disabled text input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form where one of the text inputs is set to disabled. It's important that we keep this text input but it has confused some users. They try to click and edit and think that the form is broken because they can not edit that box.

I've tried to add an onclick to trigger a window.alert box to warn them that they can't edit this text input. I haven't been able to get it to work.

Does anyone know a way using jquery that if they click on a disabled text input that it shows a window.alert?

Thanks for the help...

Comment: Any reason you can't _hide_ the input? Hidden, enabled inputs are still submitted with the form.

Comment: @Chowlett: That may be undesireable (as disabled inputs *aren't* submitted with the form).

Answer (score 4):

How about wrapping input field onto div with class and trigger it on that div ?

EDIT:

It works in Firefox if you set z-index properites, and absolute positions like this jsfiddle.net/aFnJt/3

Comment: This will only work once the wrapper is clicked. That's the result for me at least, in Firefox.

Comment: @RichardHedges: Blast, I can confirm that with FF9. Works great on Chrome and IE, but not on FF or Opera.

Comment: How about trying setting higher z-index on that div, and setting background-color: transparent; ?

Comment: @MikołajStolarski Just gave that a go. Still nothing on FF

Comment: Perhaps another way would be to find the elements position, and on click of that area run the alert. Would probably be a bit messy though.

Comment: It works if you set z-index properites, and absolute positions like this http://jsfiddle.net/aFnJt/3/

Comment: I've been working on the DIV idea, but can't seem to get it to work.  I may have to try another approach all together. Any ideas?

Comment: I Found a solution. I set the input field to readonly instead of disabled. That seemed to do the trick.

Comment: @Will, thanks, readonly does the trick for me too! Note that browsers treat such elements a bit differently (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730695/whats-the-difference-between-disabled-disabled-and-readonly-readonly-for-te). If you don't mind, I'd make an answer to your question for future visitors like me.

Answer (score 0):

Select the element with [`:disabled`](http://api.jquery.com/disabled-selector/) and then make a alert:

```
$('form').on('click', 'input:disabled', function() {
  window.alert('This input is disabled');
});
```

Comment: Click events don't fire on disabled inputs

Comment: Doesn't work. Nifty idea hooking the event on the wrapper and then filtering, but apparently jQuery follows the standard model that makes disabled elements not fire `click`.

Answer (score 0):

### Firefox compatible example

```
$(function(){
$("INPUT:disabled")
.wrap("<span>")
.parent()
.css({
    display:'inline-block',
    position:'relative'
})
.append(
    $("<span>")
    .css({
        position:'absolute',
        top:'0',
        left:'0',
        width:'100%',
        height:'100%',
        xIndex: 9999
    })
    .click(function(){alert('Disabled');})
);
})
```

---

```
$(function(){
    $("INPUT:disabled")
    .wrap("<span>")
    .parent()
    .click(function(){alert('Disabled')});
})
```

Comment: See [Mikolaj's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8929926/157247), doesn't work with Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Given the Firefox issue with [Mikolaj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8929926/157247), I think your best bet is to replace the field with a styled div or similar. If the problem is that people are confused by the input, make it clearer visually that the input is disabled (and replacing it with just text is one great way to do that).

Answer (score 0):

From a user perspective I would prefer not to see the use of an alert box. Here are two more user friendly alternatives.

http://jsfiddle.net/cPaNA/

```
$('input:disabled[value=a]').hide();              //hide it instead
$('input:disabled[value=b]').val('disabled');     //use value for a message
```

You can also use the `:disabled` pseudoselector to make the fact that it is disabled more obvious.

```
input:disabled { color: gray; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Making the field `readonly` can help, because the click event will be fired. Though be aware of the [differences in behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730695/whats-the-difference-between-disabled-disabled-and-readonly-readonly-for-te).

```
<input type="text" name="yourname" value="Bob" readonly="readonly" />
```

(thanks @Will for the idea)

Answer (score -2):

**Update** ...

Try wrapping the diabled input in a span, or div and give that element an id and use it as the jQuery selector:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ID').click(function() {
        alert('This input is disabled');
    });
});
```

link: http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: Disabled inputs don't fire `click`

Comment: Your update is just a duplicate of Mikolaj's answer using a different element (as are several other answers here). And unfortunately, doesn't work with Firefox.