# How can I set the disabled and readonly properties of a <select> and <input> element with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How can I set the disabled and readonly properties of a `<select>` and `<input>` element with jQuery? Also can someone please explain the difference. It seems to me that both properties would do the same thing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730695/whats-the-difference-between-disabled-disabled-and-readonly-readonly-for-te

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('input,select').attr('disabled','disabled')
$('input').attr('readonly','readonly')
```

likewise…

```
$('input,select').removeAttr('disabled')
$('input').removeAttr('readonly')
```

**EDIT:** You might want to read about the difference between [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) and [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/). Although relatively old [here's an official documentation](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/12/jquery-1-6-1-released/) covering it.