# Play framework 2.0 template issues

Tags: playframework-2.0, scala-template

```
@(myForm: Form[FormObject]) 

@import helper._
@import helper.twitterBootstrap._

@main("Test") {
  @form(routes.Application.save) {
    @input(myForm("number"), '_label -> "Number") { (id, name, value, args) =>
      @if(value.isEmpty) {
        <input type="text" name="@name" id="@id" value="@value">
      } else {
        <input type="text" name="@name" id="@id" value="@value" disabled>
      }
    }
    @input(myForm("startDate"), '_label -> "Start Date") { (id, name, value, args) =>
      <div class="input-append date datepicker" data-date="@value" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
        <input class="span2" size="16" type="text" value="@value"><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
      </div>
    }
    <button type="submit" class="btn" title="Save"><i class="icon-ok"></i></button>
  }
}

public class FormObject {
public String number;
public String startDate;
}
```

1. The first issue is that when the value of field 'number' is not
   empty (and therefore shown disabled) is not bind back to FormObject,
   so I lose this value.
2. The second issue is that field 'startDate' is not bind to FormObject.

   Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: It's common mistake - `disabled` attribute disables the field even from sending, so it isn't even available to play a the request time. Use `readonly` instead. ([more about `disabled` vs `readonly`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7730719/1066240))

```
    @input(myForm("number"), '_label -> "Number") { (id, name, value, args) =>
       <input type="text" name="@name" id="@id" value="@value" @if(!value.isEmpty){ readonly="readonly" }>
    }
```

Maybe you will need to use some CSS/JS for accenting that the field is readonly, otherwise often users considers it as a bug (*I can't edit this field and don't know why*)

Second: If it's really `String` field - I don't know the reason. If it's `Date` problem is caused by format change, Play can not parse automatically. You will need to parse it as well with the given format in your controller before the save/update.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that disabled caused that. The date field is just a String, so the formatting should not be the issue.

Comment: In such case try do bind it from request and use `Logger.debug(field)` to display it in the terminal. I have no idea, why simple `String` field isn't binded :/

Comment: I used the debugger to check the request, but the request does not contain the field 'startDate'. The HTML looks like this:         <div class="input-append date datepicker" data-date="" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
  <input class="span2" size="16" type="text" value=""><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
</div>