# javascript focus function not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having a jsp/html page.This page is accessed from two different links.
It is Menu1-->demo.html page and from Menu2-->demo.html page(In my case its jsp)
In the demo.html page I am having a text box which is disabled by default.

```
<input class="mytextinputtextField" type="text" id="countryOfOrigin"
readonly style="background-color:#DCDCDC"   />
```

Now when the demo.html page is accessed from Menu2 , I am checking it using a hidden parameter and again enabling the text box and setting the focus on the text box.

```
if(document.getElementById("submenu_name").value=="PM")
{
   document.getElementById("countryOfOrigin").focus();
}
```

The field is enable and the cursor is visible but if I type the text is not typed in the text box.
I need to click on the text box to enter the text.
I think it is because of the disabled and again enabling the field .
Please can any one help me to be able to type in the text box on the focus event from javascript.
I am not using JQuery and the browser is I.E 6

Comment: How do you enable your textbox?

Comment: document.getElementById("countryOfOrigin").readOnly = false;

Comment: This is one of those attributes that is there, or not there as it becomes a "property" of the element.  try `readonly="fred"` and you see, it still is read only :) as it is the "presence" of the property that drives its functionality.

Comment: I just debug it, I found that my keyup event is fired correctly for each keypress...but its not getting displayed

Comment: Could you test in a modern browser and tell us if it works?

Comment: Hi all, still I am not able to fix it....can anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
document.getElementById("countryOfOrigin").removeAttribute('readOnly');
```

jQuery version :

```
jQuery('#countryOfOrigin').removeAttr('readOnly');
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the attribute?

```
document.getElementById("countryOfOrigin").Attributes.Remove("readonly");
```

or

```
document.getElementById("countryOfOrigin").removeAttribute("readonly");
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help.
I hav found solution or may say work around.
I am pasting the code which may be useful for others

```
if(document.getElementById("submenu_name").value=="PM")
{
 document.getElementById("countryOfOrigin").focus();
 document.getElementById("countryOfOrigin").select();

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is an unofficial solution, we have to use the setTimeout() function to delay the focus() execute time.

```
setTimeout(function() { document.getElementById('myInput').focus(); }, 10);
```

See http://www.mkyong.com/javascript/focus-is-not-working-in-ie-solution/

Comment: .I tried this,but not working. Its same its sets the focus but when I type its not getting typed.

Comment: Use element.disabled instead of readOnly.
And if it doesn't work, don't disable the input, but blur the field onfocus if you d'ont want the input to be enabled.

Comment: Be aware that `disabled` behaves not the same way as `readonly` : [check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730695/whats-the-difference-between-disabled-disabled-and-readonly-readonly-for-te)

Comment: And for the second idea, i think it would be a working compromise.