# disabled fields not storing in database PHP / MYSQL

Tags: php, sql

here is the screenshot where i am stuck:

[image]

the disabled fields row are not being stored to database after submit button please help !

Also, sometimes ago it use to work but now no more.. I am really stuck what the issue is and i have not made any such changes that create such issue..

before it used to store these stuffs, when fields are disabled:

ID, website, comapny type.

but now they are not working.. please help !

Answer (score 6):

If you use `disabled` property, value of the field will not be submitted along with form.

What you have to do is use `readonly` attribute.

---

**From https://stackoverflow.com/a/7730719/1288198:**

read more about this in [this great article](http://kreotekdev.wordpress.com/2007/11/08/disabled-vs-readonly-form-fields/) or [the definition by w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.12). to quote the important part:

> **Key Differences**
>
> **The Disabled attribute**
>
> - Values for disabled form elements are not passed to the processor method. The W3C calls this a successful element.(This works similar to
>     form check boxes that are not checked.)
> - Some browsers may override or provide default styling for disabled form elements. (Gray out or emboss text) Internet Explorer
>     5.5 is particularly nasty about this.
> - Disabled form elements do not receive focus.
> - Disabled form elements are skipped in tabbing navigation.
>
> **The Read Only Attribute**
>
> - Not all form elements have a readonly attribute. Most notable, the `<SELECT>` , `<OPTION>` , and `<BUTTON>` elements do not have readonly
>     attributes (although thy both have disabled attributes)
> - Browsers provide no default overridden visual feedback that the form element is read only. (This can be a problem… see below.)
> - Form elements with the readonly attribute set will get passed to the form processor.
> - Read only form elements can receive the focus
> - Read only form elements are included in tabbed navigation.

Answer (score 1):

Try use

```
<INPUT NAME="name" VALUE="Hi There" READONLY>
```

instead of

```
<INPUT NAME="name" VALUE="Hi There" DISABLED>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get Input fields are `readonly` to prevent changes and getting values in `$_POST`.
In `select` tag use `disabled` and put hidden field for it.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can not insert disabled field, you have to make your form readonly as answered above by deepu
use

```
<input type='text' name='test' readonly="readonly" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind i got the answer.. !

i just restarted sql and did some tweaks and that works !

Comment: What did you tweak? It will be useful for other people to know how you fixed the problem.

Comment: first:  i shutdown sql; second: cleaned cache, cookies, history. third: shutdown full apache and restarted PC. fourth: Restarted Apache, SQL . and tried it.. and that worked ! just as it should.. it don't store the disabled field and save them as null.. and save rest all data as it was doing previously...  The issue overall i think was as i installed MySQL oracle benchmark .. due to it that all was started.. :\