# Webkit-user-modify not working in chrome

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4

I place certain value in input using id using jquery but i can still edit it.Code given below

```
<td><input id="txtTicketCode" style="-webkit-user-modify: read-only;"/> </td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML provides 2 keywords to prevent user's interaction of `input` elements: `disabled` and `readonly`. You should use them instead of using browser-attributed CSS.

By the way, `disabled` is a boolean attribute. No need `disabled="disabled"`.

Correct usage:

```
<td><input id="txtTicketCode" disabled /></td>
```

Last, you want read-only or disabled? Read more with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7730719/188331).

Answer (score 1):

Fixed using `<td><input id="txtTicketCode" disabled="disabled"/> </td>`