# Make HTML form data unchangeable, but still able to post

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have an HTML form that calculates total quantity and price. I can put this total into an input field to be submitted. However, I don't want the user to be able to change it. If i put it in a div and display it, it's not submitted with the form.

How do I display the total and submit it without letting the user change it?

I'm probably missing something basic here. Any help appreciated.

Comment: just give the input a `readonly` attribute...it's from the 90's. 
why would you want to submit something the server already knows anyway?

Comment: vsync, This is it. Submit this as an answer and I'll choose it. It's for a client that wants it this way.

Comment: ok, done. you can now choose it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give the input a [readonly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/readonly) attribute:

### `<input readonly value='cannot be changed' />`

Answer (score 5):

If you want no security (via tamper prevention) use the [readonly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/readonly) attribute:

**HTML5**

```
<input type="text" value="MY_DATE" readonly>
```

**HTML4**

```
<input type="text" value="MY_DATE" readonly="readonly" />
```

The `type="text"` can be omitted, but I personally find it helps newer developers see what type the input is at first glance.

Your best bet (for proper security) is to either encrypt or sign the data and send it as a hidden form element. Then once it comes back to the server you can either decrypt it (to keep using it) or check the signature to ensure it hasn't been tampered with.

Then from a frontend point of view you can just make the data not an input (or readonly) and then you should be golden.
The technique is used a lot by web frameworks such as CakePHP when it supplies the id in a hidden element, and signs it to ensure no tampering.

**Server**

```
signed = sha(date, salt);
```

**Frontend**

```
input[type="hidden"].value = signed;
input[type="text"][readonly].value = date;
```

**Server (on submit)**

```
if(signed === sha(POST[date], salt) {
    //date has not changed
} else {
    // date has changed
}
```

For a11y (accessibility) you should still use a form element when showing data related to what is being sent off, so using a text input is advised over a div.
Using `readonly` is far better off than `disabled` as disabled will remove the input from the request all together, resulting in your server not receiving it.
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730695/whats-the-difference-between-disabled-disabled-and-readonly-readonly-for-ht).

Here is a quick snippet of how to do it in PHP.

**Server**

```
$salt = '...'; //This should be stored securely in your application.
$date = ... //However you are storing your date.
$signed_date = hash('sha512', $salt . $date);
```

**Frontend**

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $signed_date; ?>" name="signed_date" />
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $date; ?>" readonly name="date" />
```

**Server (on submit)**

```
$salt = '...';
$date = &$_POST['date'];
$signed_date = &$_POST['signed_date'];

if(hash('sha512', $salt . $date) === $signed_date) {
    echo "wooo!";
} else {
    echo "ohhh";
}
```

Comment: Did you know that user's tampering fields you do not want them to tamper can cause huge security risks?

Comment: well it's a given fact that ANY data which comes from the browser **must** be validated and cannot be trusted. that is a fact. it's not something I should even mention since it's so basic like breathing air. So, we are only left with client-side coding here.

Comment: You say that. But OP clearly does not have too much experience. Never assume a person's knowledge, guide them through every step of the process and show them the pros and cons of a situation.

Comment: I agree. but you don't need all this, since the server shouldn't be doing anything with the data anyway.

Comment: They server does need to do something, it needs to process the date. You have no idea on OP's setup. For all we know he has a stateless system which requires the client to send all the data required, and is never held in either memory or the database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56861/discussion-between-jshthornton-and-vsync).