# Cant Get Post value Codeigniter 3

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, string-parsing, codeigniter-3

im using codeigniter 3 today and i want get post data from my view files, here my view files

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url('action/getpost'); ?>" method="post">
<div class="row marketing">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input  disabled required type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname_field" id="firstname_field" placeholder="First name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input  disabled required type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname_field" id="lastname_field" placeholder="last Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input  disabled required type="text" class="form-control" name="cardholderid_field" id="cardholderid_field" placeholder="Cardholder ID">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input  disabled required type="text" class="form-control" name="cardnumber_field" id="cardnumber_field" placeholder="Card Number">
    </div>
    </div>
</div
</form>
```

and heres my controller..

```
function getpost()
{
    if($this->input->post('submit')){
        $firstname = $this->input->post('firstname_field');
        $lastname = $this->input->post('lastname_field');
        $cardholder = $this->input->post('cardholderid_field');
        $cardnumber = $this->input->post('cardnumber_field');

        $data = array(
                      'firstname' => $firstname,
                      'lastname' => $lastname,
                      'cardholder' => $cardholder,
                      'cardnumber' => $cardnumber
                      );

        print_r($data);
```

im always get result like this,

```
Array ( [firstname] => [lastname] => [cardholder] => [cardnumber] => )
```

anyone can help?

thanks buddies'

Comment: As i know if an input field is disabled its data not send when form is submitted. Use `readonly` instead of `disabled`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use readonly instead of disable...

deference between readonly and disable [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730695/whats-the-difference-between-disabled-disabled-and-readonly-readonly-for-ht).

if u r using readonly u hve to specify value and give button

in view

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url('action/getpost'); ?>" method="post">
<div class="row marketing">
   <div class="col-lg-6">
   <div class="form-group">
       <input  value="firstname" readonly required type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" id="firstname_field" placeholder="First name">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
        <input  value="lastname" readonly required type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname" id="lastname_field" placeholder="last Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input  value="" readonly required type="text" class="form-control" name="cardholderid" id="cardholderid_field" placeholder="Cardholder ID">
    </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <input  value="cardnumber" readonly required type="text" class="form-control" name="cardnumber" id="cardnumber_field" placeholder="Card Number">
   </div>
  <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div
</form>
```

in controller

```
function getpost()
{
  print_r($this->input->post());
}
```