# How to hide soft keyboard without cordova's plugins and without lost focus

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, dom-events

I'd like to hide the Android native keyboard when I do click over an `<input type=text>` without plugins and without lost the focus of the `input`.

With JavaScript I can detect when the keyboard show or hide, but I'd like to hide when I want it.

The `backbutton` hides the keyboard when it is showing, so, I think that I could trigger the backbutton click event when I detect a `showkeyboard` event, but it doesn't work.

```
document.addEventListener("showkeyboard", 
    function(){ 
        alert("Keyboard is ON"); 
        $("backbutton").trigger('click'); // Doesn't work effect
    }, false);

document.addEventListener("hidekeyboard", 
    function(){ 
        alert("Keyboard is OFF");

    }, false);
```

Comment: readonly-attribute works and it should still be able to receive focus as it states here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730695/whats-the-difference-between-disabled-disabled-and-readonly-readonly-for-ht

Answer (score 0):

first in your mainactivity import :

```
    import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
    import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
```

Then add a javascriptinterface in onCreate Method :

```
   super.appView.addJavascriptInterface(new JSInterface(), "testInterface");
```

After that add the follwing code in Mainactivity class :

```
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void hideKeyboard() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                try {
                    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Service.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(<MainactivityClass>.this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Now from HTML, call the native hideKeyboard() method in the input box like this way :

```
    <input type="text" onfocus="window.testInterface.hideKeyboard()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using directly

```
document.getElementById('input_field_to_focus').focus();
```

This adds focus to the input field but does not invoke the soft keyboard.
The keyboard open event is not triggered on Android unless it is from a click event.

Refer the link:http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27438