# text_field with default value can not save to db in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to save the text_field to database with defaut value ,but it's not work.

```
<p>
<%= f.label :用户id %><br>
<%= f.text_field :user_id ,:value => "#{current_user.try :id}", disabled: true %>
</p>
<p>
<%= f.label :用户昵称 %><br>
<% user = User.find current_user.id%>
<%= f.text_field :name ,:value => user.name , disabled: true%>
</p>
```

Comment: can you show the error log?

Comment: no error , just :user_id , :name is null , but other column is saved correctly.

Comment: ok still show the log of past data..

Comment: are you sure you whitelisted user_is and name in your strong parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `disabled: true` to `readonly: true` if you want the field to be un-editable but still submit a value.

"READONLY and DISABLED both remove the functionality of the input field, but to different degrees. READONLY locks the field: the user cannot change the value. DISABLED does the same thing but takes it further: the user cannot use the field in any way, not to highlight the text for copying, not to select the checkbox, not to submit the form. **In fact, a disabled field is not even sent if the form is submitted.**"

Reference:

http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_INPUT_DISABLED.html
http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.12

Also see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7730719/2113461