# Form auto select when input is disabled

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to auto select text in an input field when it is clicked, but when the field is disabled the auto select doesn't work.

Here is my Html:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="gameId" select-on-click disabled="true">
```

And here is my JavaScript:

```
angular.module('Admin').directive('selectOnClick', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            element.on('click', function(){
                this.select();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

I would like the text to be selectable when the form is disabled, how can I do that?

Comment: PLUNKER OT FIDDEL demo would be great :)

Comment: Text can't be selected when the input is disabled, it just doesn't work that way

Comment: So, I am going to have to make it a div then...

Comment: readonly attrib should give you a similar result

Comment: @OliverBarnwell that does exactly what I want!

Comment: Cool. I'll submit it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `disabled` attribute doesn't allow text to be selected. A solution is to use the `readonly` attribute.

However it should be noted that they don't provide exactly the same behaviour, this is expanded upon in more detail in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730695/whats-the-difference-between-disabled-disabled-and-readonly-readonly-for-ht)