# kendo ui dropdownList Disable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui

I am working with kendo ui with asp.net mvc 5. I have some condition where I have to show the kendo ui dropdownlist disabled, but when I submit the from (post) the model field which I have used to bind the drop-down list contains null instead of value.

Here is my code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(i => i.CallTypeId)
    .Name("CallTypeId")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
    .DataTextField("MasterValueName")
    .DataValueField("MasterValueId")
    .Enable(false)
    .DataSource(source =>
    {
        source.Read(read =>
        {
            read.Action("GetCallType", "Common", new { Area = "" });
        });
    })
    .OptionLabel("Select Call Type")
)
```

Is there any other alternate to disable the kendo dropdownlist but remember I need the selected value.
Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 2):

You don't receive the value because your control is disabled.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7730719/1134380) all disabled elements are not passed to form processor.

I think that you have to use the `ReadOnly` method instead of `Enable`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are posting the form with JavaScript (or have that option), you can enable the field just before posting so that the model contains the value:

View:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Button()  // hidden post button to be "clicked" from JavaScript
    .Name("btnPostForm")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { type = "submit", style = "display:none", name = "Command" })
)
```

Script:

```
// Enable the drop-down.
$('#CallTypeId').getKendoDropDownList().enable(true);

// Post the form.
var postButton = $('#btnPostForm');
postButton.attr('value', 'SaveForm');  // optional command name for controller to read
postButton.click();
```