# Store query element into database

Tags: php, jquery, database, mysqli

table is under loop

```
<table>
<tr><input class="txt form-control"  name="balance[]" type="text" placeholder="Balance" /></tr>
</table>
```

,and the balance is added from all the tr

*total balance* is shown on the *debtsum*. And it is done by jquery

```
<div class="col-lg-3"> <input class="debtsum form-control " id="debt" type="text" name="totaldebt" placeholder="Total Debt" disabled /> </div>
```

**Query to store data into database :**

```
    $totaldebt = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['totaldebt']);//to store total debt in the database
    $table_customer_data="insert into
   tbl_customer_data(totaldebt) values ('".$totaldebt."');
```

**Jquery script to add all the data of class txt :**

```
<script>
function calculateSum() {
var sum = 0;
$(".txt").each(function () {

//add only if the value is number
if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
sum += parseFloat(this.value);      
}
});
$('#debt').val(sum.toFixed(2));
}

$("table").on("keyup", ".txt", function () {
calculateSum();
});

</script>
```

The jquery function is working properly, and sums all the input value of balance. But when i submit form to store all the value into database it stores nothing.

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is issue due to disabled property in your element.

> disabled element isn't editable and isn't sent on submit.

I think you can take readonly.

> a readonly element is just not editable, but gets sent when the
>   according form submits.

for more information please [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730695/whats-the-difference-between-disabled-disabled-and-readonly-readonly-for-ht)

Comment: Thanks Apoorva for the answer and for the information now code is working properly.