# Disabling submit button cancels submit event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

On my client-side page I attach a listener to the submit button:

```
$(function() {                                                                  
  $('button[type="submit"]').click(submitButtonClicked);                      
});
```

and I'd like to disable the button and all other form input elements when the button is clicked:

```
function submitButtonClicked(ev) {                                              
  if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {                                           
    return false; // Reject actions when disabled, preventDefault() and stopPropagation()                          
  }                                                                           
  $('form').find('input, select, textarea, button')                       
           .prop('disabled', true) // This call is the culprit?
           .blur();                                                       
  return true; // Submit form.
}
```

The above function seems to swallow the event, and no form submit arrives at the server. However, if I remove the `prop('disabled', true)` then the form submits just fine, but also all form elements stay enabled and reactive.

Why is that? I assumed that returning `true` will cause the event `ev` to continue propagating, whether or not the button is being disabled.

Comment: Rather than disabling the inputs, can you put them into a readonly state as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730695/whats-the-difference-between-disabled-disabled-and-readonly-readonly-for-ht. It should be as easy as: `$('form').find('input, select, textarea, button').prop('readonly', true).blur();`. Perhaps that will prevent the user from changing the contents but allow the request to continue processing?...

Comment: I don't want to post this as an answer because it doesn't really answer the question at hand. However, as a workaround you could replace `return true` with `$('form').submit()`. I'm getting the same result as you after no longer disabling the button. I assume it's an attempt to prevent a submit from going through unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$('form').find('input, select, textarea, button')
```

to

```
$('form').find('input:not([type=submit]), select, textarea, button')
```

Comment: Might take a look at the questions again: he's using a `button` ;)

Comment: That excludes the submit button from being disabled. Does that mean that a disabling the `submit` button cancels the form?

Answer (score 0):

Because the button element has been disabled the browser uses the disabled property to determine whether to fire the submit event. See the below example where the click event is triggered but the form is not submitted

```
$("#button").click(function()
{
    console.log("disabling");
    $("#button").prop("disabled", true);
    console.log("disabled");
    return true;
});

$("#form").submit(function(){
    console.log("Submit");
});

$("#button").click();
$("#button").click();
```

Comment: So the event _does_ propagate, but the browser cancels the submit because of the now-disabled `submit` button... ?

Comment: That the way I understand it yes

Comment: You are correct, according to [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730695/whats-the-difference-between-disabled-disabled-and-readonly-readonly-for-ht#7730719) :)

Comment: I didn't edit it in, but normal click events on the html still fire on both click calls

Answer (score 0):

Disable your form after form.submit.

```
...
setTimeout(function(){
    $('form').find('input, select, textarea, button')                       
       .prop('disabled', true);}, 200);//setTimeout
return true;
```