# Django modelform field how to make disabled and prevent tampering?

Tags: django, django-forms

There is this disabled attribute. But i am not able to apply it to the modelform fields. I am not sure how to. I can add it to forms.Form easily. But since I am using widgets I just dont know where to insert it.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/#disabled

```
class TestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = ['date']
        widgets = {'date': forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly': 'readonly'})}
```

Comment: You can add the attribute: `forms.TextInput(attrs={'disabled': 'disabled'}),`

Answer (score 6):

I was facing a situation when I wanted to disable some fields when creating . And some fields disabled when editing.

**My Env:** Python 3, Django 2.1

**My Form:**

```
class AddInvoiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    disabled_fields = ['inv_type', 'report', 'subsidiary']
    class Meta:
        model = models.Invoice
        fields = ('inv_type', 'report', 'subsidiary', 'rate_card', 'reviewed')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AddInvoiceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        instance = getattr(self, 'instance', None)
        if instance and instance.pk:
            for field in self.disabled_fields:
                self.fields[field].disabled = True
        else:
            self.fields['reviewed'].disabled = True
```

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this, assuming that your `date` field is `forms.DateField` and that you want to use `TextInput` widget:

```
class TestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.TextInput, disabled=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = ['date']
```

This will override the default field definition which is created from your `Test` model definition.

> The disabled boolean argument, when set to True, disables a form field using the disabled HTML attribute so that it won’t be editable by users. Even if a user tampers with the field’s value submitted to the server, it will be ignored in favor of the value from the form’s initial data.

Read about [readonly  vs disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730695/whats-the-difference-between-disabled-disabled-and-readonly-readonly-for-ht) HTML input attributes.

The key note to take out from the above SO post is:

> A `readonly` element is just not editable, but gets sent when the according `form` submits. a `disabled` element isn't editable and isn't sent on submit.

From above quote, setting `disabled=True` is enough, so you dont need to set `readonly` attribute on your widget.

Comment: Can't someone just click on "inspect" on the form entry and modify the content and the resubmit the form?

Comment: @FedericoGentile see the quote I use in my answer. It says 'Even if a user tampers with the field’s value submitted to the server, it will be ignored in favor of the value from the form’s initial data.'. Thats what official Django docs say (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#disabled)

Comment: Hello, I just tested it on my own and with readonly I am still able to modify the value and submit it. As a matter of fact when I check the database where I store the data I actually see the modified value

Answer (score 3):

```
class TestForm(forms.ModelForm):
date = forms.CharField(disabled=True)
class Meta:
    model = Test
    fields = ['date']

    widgets = {
        'date': forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly': 'readonly'}),
    }
```

Comment: are you sure that will work? How will it knnow that the variable date and the field date are related to each other/

Comment: You are using model form.. So django will relate that implicitly