# how can i make this disabled input act as an enabled one and scroll when you click the buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

I'm playing with an idea for a keypad login.  My question is how can I make the disabled input behave like a regular, enabled input?  I want the text to scroll as you click the buttons if the text is larger than the input length.

```js
function setOne(){ document.getElementById('someText').value += "A"; }
function setTwo(){ document.getElementById('someText').value += "B"; }
```

```html
<input id="someText" type="text" disabled="disabled">

<div>
<button onclick="setOne();">A</button>
<button onclick="setTwo();">B</button>
</div>
```

No jQuery please. Thanks You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabled inputs can not receive a focus, [Please read here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7730719/2630817) disabled can not trigger the text selection, Try readonly which will receive the focus you want to add.

```js
function setOne(){ document.getElementById('someText').value += "A";focus(); }
function setTwo(){ document.getElementById('someText').value += "B";focus(); }
function focus(){
var foo =document.getElementById('someText');
foo.focus();
foo.setSelectionRange(foo.value.length,foo.value.length);

}
```

```css
#someText{
opacity:0.3;
background-color:gray;
}
```

```html
<input id="someText" type="text" readonly>

<div>
<button onclick="setOne();">A</button>
<button onclick="setTwo();">B</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Edge or IE any thoughts on that?

Comment: @Jonny check out this seems to be bug :https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/15637833/

Comment: what would be the drawback of using  dir="rtl"  with the input?  This seems to work on ie and edge?   Any problems with processing the data

Comment: @Jonny I do not think so, you can try it with rtl too, just make sure you are appending data currently in rtl you need to prepend and set focus accordingly.

Comment: I didn't think it would have much of an effect i used document.write to check it and the input was the same.