# Making all form inputs to be in readonly mode while clicking submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, radio-button, readonly

I have a form when the submit button is clicked form's all inputs needs to be in read-only mode and hide submit button and also displays submitting text. For this I coded:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit_text").hide(); //Hiding submit_text
  $("#testsubmitbutton").click(function() {
    $("#testsubmitbutton").hide(); //Hiding submit button
    $("#submit_text").show(); //Showing submit_text

    $("#testform :input").prop('readonly', true); //Making all inputs to readonly

  });
});
```

```css
.hiddenFramehideclass {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  left: -1px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe name="hiddenFrame" class="hiddenFramehideclass"></iframe>

<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="testform" target="hiddenFrame">

  Question 1
  <div class="question_container">
    <div class="question_div">
      <p>Question?</p>
      <input type="hidden" name="qid1" value="22">
      <div class="option_div">
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="checka1" value="A">
        <label for="checka1">
          <p>A</p>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="option_div">
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="checkb1" value="B">
        <label for="checkb1">
          <p>B</p>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="option_div">
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="checkc1" value="C">
        <label for="checkc1">
          <p>C</p>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="option_div">
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="checkd1" value="D">
        <label for="checkd1">
          <p>D</p>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="option_div">
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="checke1" value="E">
        <label for="checke1">
          <p>None of the above</p>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="" type="submit" name="testsubmitbutton" id="testsubmitbutton">Submit</button>
  <span id="submit_text">Submitting please <b>do not</b> refresh!</span>
</form>
```

When I click the submit button it hides the submit button and shows submitting text. But it doesn't change the input property to read-only mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For radio button use `disabled` property:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit_text").hide(); //Hiding submit_text
  $("#testsubmitbutton").click(function() {
    $("#testsubmitbutton").hide(); //Hiding submit button
    $("#submit_text").show(); //Showing submit_text

    $("#testform :input").prop('disabled', true); //Making all inputs to disabled

  });
});
```

```css
.hiddenFramehideclass {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  left: -1px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe name="hiddenFrame" class="hiddenFramehideclass"></iframe>

<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="testform" target="hiddenFrame">

  Question 1
  <div class="question_container">
    <div class="question_div">
      <p>Question?</p>
      <input type="hidden" name="qid1" value="22">
      <div class="option_div">
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="checka1" value="A">
        <label for="checka1">
          <p>A</p>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="option_div">
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="checkb1" value="B">
        <label for="checkb1">
          <p>B</p>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="option_div">
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="checkc1" value="C">
        <label for="checkc1">
          <p>C</p>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="option_div">
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="checkd1" value="D">
        <label for="checkd1">
          <p>D</p>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="option_div">
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="checke1" value="E">
        <label for="checke1">
          <p>None of the above</p>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="" type="submit" name="testsubmitbutton" id="testsubmitbutton">Submit</button>
  <span id="submit_text">Submitting please <b>do not</b> refresh!</span>
</form>
```

If you want send the selected value to the server then probably you can set the `pointer-events` to `none` which will indicate that the element is not the target of pointer events:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit_text").hide(); //Hiding submit_text
  $("#testsubmitbutton").click(function() {
    $("#testsubmitbutton").hide(); //Hiding submit button
    $("#submit_text").show(); //Showing submit_text
    $("#testform :input").css({'pointer-events':'none', 'opacity':'.5'});
    $('.option_div p').css({'opacity':'.5'});
    $('.option_div p').click(false);
    console.log($("form").serialize());
  });
});
```

```css
.hiddenFramehideclass {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  left: -1px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe name="hiddenFrame" class="hiddenFramehideclass"></iframe>

<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="testform" target="hiddenFrame">

  Question 1
  <div class="question_container">
    <div class="question_div">
      <p>Question?</p>
      <input type="hidden" name="qid1" value="22">
      <div class="option_div">
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="checka1" value="A">
        <label for="checka1">
          <p>A</p>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="option_div">
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="checkb1" value="B">
        <label for="checkb1">
          <p>B</p>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="option_div">
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="checkc1" value="C">
        <label for="checkc1">
          <p>C</p>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="option_div">
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="checkd1" value="D">
        <label for="checkd1">
          <p>D</p>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="option_div">
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="checke1" value="E">
        <label for="checke1">
          <p>None of the above</p>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="" type="submit" name="testsubmitbutton" id="testsubmitbutton">Submit</button>
  <span id="submit_text">Submitting please <b>do not</b> refresh!</span>
</form>
```

Comment: Will that submit the true checked values to the server? As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7730719/12912453) it will not.

Comment: @jagu2020, please check the second answer to handle the issue:)

Comment: I guess, we also have to set `pointer-events` to `none` to labels. As it is checking the radio if we click the label.

Comment: For the label I added: `$(".label_pointer_event").css({'pointer-events':'none', 'opacity':'.5'});`

Comment: @jagu2020, I think that will not work as you expect, please check the updated answer with the possible solution:)

Comment: @jagu2020, I think that will not work as you expect, please check the updated answer with the possible solution:)

Answer (score 0):

Readonly does not work on radio buttons, you can use `disabled: true`, however...

See this answer to understand the difference between disabled and readonly: [What's the difference between disabled="disabled" and readonly="readonly" for HTML form input fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730695/whats-the-difference-between-disabled-disabled-and-readonly-readonly-for-ht)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit_text").hide(); //Hiding submit_text
  $("#testsubmitbutton").click(function() {
    $("#testsubmitbutton").hide(); //Hiding submit button
    $("#submit_text").show(); //Showing submit_text

    $("#testform :input").attr('disabled', true); //Making all inputs to readonly

  });
});
```

```css
.hiddenFramehideclass {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  left: -1px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe name="hiddenFrame" class="hiddenFramehideclass"></iframe>

<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="testform" target="hiddenFrame">

  Question 1
  <div class="question_container">
    <div class="question_div">
      <p>Question?</p>
      <input type="hidden" name="qid1" value="22">
      <div class="option_div">
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="checka1" value="A">
        <label for="checka1">
          <p>A</p>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="option_div">
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="checkb1" value="B">
        <label for="checkb1">
          <p>B</p>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="option_div">
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="checkc1" value="C">
        <label for="checkc1">
          <p>C</p>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="option_div">
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="checkd1" value="D">
        <label for="checkd1">
          <p>D</p>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="option_div">
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="checke1" value="E">
        <label for="checke1">
          <p>None of the above</p>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="" type="submit" name="testsubmitbutton" id="testsubmitbutton">Submit</button>
  <span id="submit_text">Submitting please <b>do not</b> refresh!</span>
</form>
```

Comment: Will that submit the true checked values to the server? As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7730719/12912453) it will not

Comment: It will not, however, you could use css to disable pointer events and send your data via ajax... define a class  in css, adjust opacity and then addClass('disabledPointerClass'), problem is you would also have to use e.preventDefault() so the page would not refresh which means sending your form data via ajax/json