# Display function depending on the classes inside the element - Javascript vanilla

Tags: javascript, html

**TLDR** I don't know how to write a function `onclick("sl") display content with class "sl"&& class "lng" hide everything else with class "lng" && class "(en, de, it, hr, ru)"`

Hello,

I'm making a multi-language registration page. I'm currently stuck as I don't know how to write/modify a function which would detect if an element has two specific classes (class lng and class sl, en, de, it, hr, or ru), and depending on the combination display the content (`display: none;` or `display: inline-block;`).

Additionally I would like the content of the placeholder to change depending on the selected language.

**Edit** Working `display: none;` / `display: inline;`

Edited JS

```
        const lngs = document.getElementsByClassName("lng");

        function init() {
            for (var i = 0; i < lngs.length; i++) {
                lngs[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }

        init();

        function setLanguage(language) {

        debugger
        console.log(language);
            for (var i = 0; i < lngs.length; i++) {
                if (lngs[i].className.includes(language)) {
                    lngs[i].style.display = "inline";
                } else {
                    lngs[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
```

Edited HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <img class="background-image" />
        <header>
            <div class="top-nav-logo">
                <img class="top-logo" src="assets/Logo_Sava.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="top-language">
                <div>
                    <input type="image" id="slo" class="zastave" src="assets/drzave/Slo.png" onclick="setLanguage('sl')">
                    <input type="image" id="ang" class="zastave" src="assets/drzave/Ang.png" onclick="setLanguage('en')">
                    <input type="image" id="nem" class="zastave" src="assets/drzave/Nem.png" onclick="setLanguage('de')">
                    <input type="image" id="ita" class="zastave" src="assets/drzave/Ita.png" onclick="setLanguage('it')">
                    <input type="image" id="hrv" class="zastave" src="assets/drzave/Hrv.png" onclick="setLanguage('hr')">
                    <input type="image" id="rus" class="zastave" src="assets/drzave/Rus.png" onclick="setLanguage('ru')">
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>

        <div class="pasica">
            <img src=""/>
        </div>
        <div class="center-div">
            <div class="registerTitle">
                <div class="lng si">
                    Slo - Register
                </div>
                <div class="lng en">
                    Eng - Register
                </div>
                <div class="lng de">
                    Deu - Register
                </div>
                <div class="lng it">
                    Ita - Register
                </div>
                <div class="lng hr">
                    Hrv - Register
                </div>
                <div class="lng ru">
                    Rus - Register
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="registerForm">
                <form accept-charset="utf-8" name="form" onsubmit="return false;" method="post" id="form">
                    <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" required maxlength="50" minlength="1" placeholder="Janez" 
                    onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Janez'" /><br />
                    <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" required maxlength="50" minlength="1" placeholder="Novak" 
                    onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Novak'" /><br />

                    <span class="lng sl radioS">Spol: </span>
                    <span class="lng en radioS">Gender: </span>
                    <span class="lng de radioS">Spol DE: </span>
                    <span class="lng it radioS">Gendero IT: </span>
                    <span class="lng hr radioS">Spolov: </span>
                    <span class="lng ru radioS">секс: </span><br /><br />
                        <div class="radioC"><label><input type="radio" name="spol" value="M">   <span class="lng sl">Moški SI</span>
                                                                                                <span class="lng en">Moški EN</span>
                                                                                                <span class="lng de">Moški DE</span>
                                                                                                <span class="lng it">Moški IT</span>
                                                                                                <span class="lng hr">Moški HR</span>
                                                                                                <span class="lng ru">Moški RU</span>
                        </label></div><br />
                        <div class="radioC"><label><input type="radio" name="spol" value="Z">   <span class="lng sl">Ženski SI</span>
                                                                                                <span class="lng en">Ženski EN</span>
                                                                                                <span class="lng de">Ženski DE</span>
                                                                                                <span class="lng it">Ženski IT</span>
                                                                                                <span class="lng hr">Ženski HR</span>
                                                                                                <span class="lng ru">Ženski RU</span>
                        </label></div><br />
                        <div class="radioC"><label><input type="radio" name="spol" value="O">   <span class="lng sl">Ostalo SI</span>
                                                                                                <span class="lng en">Ostalo EN</span>
                                                                                                <span class="lng de">Ostalo DE</span>
                                                                                                <span class="lng it">Ostalo IT</span>
                                                                                                <span class="lng hr">Ostalo HR</span>
                                                                                                <span class="lng ru">Ostalo RU</span>
                        </label></div><br /><br />

                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" autofocus="autofocus" required placeholder="moj@email.com"
                    onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'moj@email.com'" />
                    <br />
                    <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit_ok" name="submit_ok" /> <br />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/language.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/myScript.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/language.js"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Registration</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <img class="background-image" />
        <header>
            <div class="top-nav-logo">
                <img class="top-logo" src="assets/Logo_Sava.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="top-language">
                <div>
                    <input type="image" id="slo" class="zastave" src="assets/drzave/Slo.png" onclick="setLanguage('sl')">
                    <input type="image" id="ang" class="zastave" src="assets/drzave/Ang.png" onclick="setLanguage('en')">
                    <input type="image" id="nem" class="zastave" src="assets/drzave/Nem.png" onclick="setLanguage('de')">
                    <input type="image" id="ita" class="zastave" src="assets/drzave/Ita.png" onclick="setLanguage('it')">
                    <input type="image" id="hrv" class="zastave" src="assets/drzave/Hrv.png" onclick="setLanguage('hr')">
                    <input type="image" id="rus" class="zastave" src="assets/drzave/Rus.png" onclick="setLanguage('ru')">
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div class="center-div">
            <div class="registerTitle">
                <div class="lng" class="sl">
                    Slo - Register
                </div>
                <div class="lng" class="en">
                    Eng - Register
                </div>
                <div class="lng" class="de">
                    Deu - Register
                </div>
                <div class="lng" class="it">
                    Ita - Register
                </div>
                <div class="lng" class="hr">
                    Hrv - Register
                </div>
                <div class="lng" class="ru">
                    Rus - Register
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="registerForm">
                <form accept-charset="utf-8" name="form" onsubmit="return false;" method="post" id="form">
                    <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" required maxlength="50" minlength="1" placeholder="Janez" 
                    onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Janez'" /><br />
                    <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" required maxlength="50" minlength="1" placeholder="Novak" 
                    onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Novak'" /><br />

                    <span class="lng" class="sl" class="radioS">Spol: </span>
                    <span class="lng" class="en" class="radioS">Gender: </span>
                    <span class="lng" class="de" class="radioS">Spol DE: </span>
                    <span class="lng" class="it" class="radioS">Spol IT: </span>
                    <span class="lng" class="hr" class="radioS">Spol HR: </span>
                    <span class="lng" class="ru" class="radioS">Spol RU: </span><br /><br />
                        <div class="radioC"><label><input type="radio" name="spol" value="M">   <span class="lng" class="sl">Moški SI</span>
                                                                                                <span class="lng" class="en">Moški EN</span>
                                                                                                <span class="lng" class="de">Moški DE</span>
                                                                                                <span class="lng" class="it">Moški IT</span>
                                                                                                <span class="lng" class="hr">Moški HR</span>
                                                                                                <span class="lng" class="ru">Moški RU</span>
                        </label></div><br />
                        <div class="radioC"><label><input type="radio" name="spol" value="Z">   <span class="lng" class="sl">Ženski SI</span>
                                                                                                <span class="lng" class="en">Ženski EN</span>
                                                                                                <span class="lng" class="de">Ženski DE</span>
                                                                                                <span class="lng" class="it">Ženski IT</span>
                                                                                                <span class="lng" class="hr">Ženski HR</span>
                                                                                                <span class="lng" class="ru">Ženski RU</span>
                        </label></div><br />
                        <div class="radioC"><label><input type="radio" name="spol" value="O">   <span class="lng" class="sl">Ostalo SI</span>
                                                                                                <span class="lng" class="en">Ostalo EN</span>
                                                                                                <span class="lng" class="de">Ostalo DE</span>
                                                                                                <span class="lng" class="it">Ostalo IT</span>
                                                                                                <span class="lng" class="hr">Ostalo HR</span>
                                                                                                <span class="lng" class="ru">Ostalo RU</span>
                        </label></div><br /><br />

                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" autofocus="autofocus" required placeholder="moj@email.com"
                    onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'moj@email.com'" />
                    <br />
                    <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit_ok" name="submit_ok" /> <br />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript - What I currently have and doesn't work

```
        let fname = document.getElementById("fname");
        let lname = document.getElementById("lname");
        let email = document.getElementById("email");

        function setInputs(language) {
            var jeziki;
            var i;
            jeziki = document.getElementsByClassName("lng");
            console.log(jeziki);
            for (var i=0;i<jeziki.length;i++){
                if (jeziki[i].getElementsByClassName === "sl") {    
                    fname.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Janez');
                    lname.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Novak');
                    email.setAttribute('placeholder', 'moj@email.si');
                } else if (jeziki[i].getElementsByClassName === "en"){
                    fname.setAttribute('placeholder', 'John');
                    lname.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Doe');
                    email.setAttribute('placeholder', 'my@email.com');
                } else if (jeziki[i].getElementsByClassName === "de"){
                    fname.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Comisar');
                    lname.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Rex');
                    email.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Rex@hou.dre');
                } else if (jeziki[i].getElementsByClassName === "it"){
                    fname.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Mak');
                    lname.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Aron');
                    email.setAttribute('placeholder', 'forza@email.it');
                } else if (jeziki[i].getElementsByClassName === "hr"){
                    fname.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Mirko');
                    lname.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Mirkic');
                    email.setAttribute('placeholder', 'nase@more.hr');
                } else if (jeziki[i].getElementsByClassName === "ru"){
                    fname.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Milan');
                    lname.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Rusky');
                    email.setAttribute('placeholder', 'rus@go.ru');
                } else {
                    fname.setAttribute('placeholder', 'John');
                    lname.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Doe');
                    email.setAttribute('placeholder', 'my@email.com');
                }
            }
        }
```

Javascript - worked, but I had to remove ID's and the setup of the page was different then (every language had it's own form).

```
        function setLanguage(language) {
            var lngs;
            var i;
            lngs = document.getElementsByClassName("lng"); //array vseh lng-jev
            console.log(lngs);
            for (var i=0;i<lngs.length;i++){
                if (lngs[i].getElementsByClassName(language) !== language) {    
                    lngs[i].style.display="none";
                } else {
                    lngs[i].style.display="inline-block";
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you considered checking against classlist? `e = element; if ( e.classList.contains('sli') &&  e.classList.contains('Ing')) {
    // do some stuff
}`
  also declare your classes like this: `class="Ing de"` rather than having 2 separate class elements

Comment: `<div class="lng" class="de"> Deu - Register</div>`. Having multiple class attributes on single element, will consider only first class and ignore the other classes. Add multiple classes to element using space. i:e `<div class="lng de"> Deu - Register</div>`.

Comment: @Tijmen i have not =) will give it a try.

Comment: @random thanks, I didn't know that

Comment: Why does `setInputs` ignore its parameter?

Comment: `const placeholders = { en: { fname: "John", lname: "...", mail: "..." }, de: { fname: "Kommissar", lname: "Rex", mail: "..." }, ... }; function setInputs(language) { /*...*/ const values = placeholders[language]; /*...*/ fname.setAttribute("placeholder", values.fname); /*...*/ }`

Comment: thanks, this makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this is first to hide everything, then show the elements that should be visible

```
var hide = ".lng";
var show = ".lng.sl";

document.querySelectorAll(hide).forEach(function() {
  this.style.display = "none";
});
document.querySelectorAll(show).forEach(function() {
  this.style.display = "inline-block";
});
```

Comment: I had something else set up for this, but with changes to the html that doesn't work any more. thanks, will give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (jeziki[i].getElementsByClassName === "sl")
```

Here you are comparing a function `getElementsByClassName` to a string, which is always `false`.

You should check whether the element contains said class:

```
if (jeziki[i].classList.contains("sl"))
```

Also, it would be better to create an array of mappings of languages to names/emails, so you don't have to have so many if conditions:

```
var mappings = [
    {
        language: "sl",
        fname: "Janez",
        lname: "Novak"
    },
    {
        language: "hr",
        fname: "Mirko",
        lname: "Mirkic"
    }
];
```

And then the whole code can be much shorter:

```
jeziki = document.getElementsByClassName("lng");
mapping = mappings.find(mapping => jezik.classList.contains(mapping.language));
```

Then just use the mapping:

```
fname.setAttribute('placeholder', mapping.fname);
lname.setAttribute('placeholder', mapping.lname);
email.setAttribute('placeholder', mapping.email);
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try. Is the question understanable? I can overcomplicate things sometimes.

Comment: Thanks. It does look way more managable =) currently `if (jeziki[i].classList.contains("sl"))` is still not working.

Comment: Hey. Could you explain how I would implement this mapping inside the function? I have updated the question with the working `display: none;` / `display:inline;`.